# Where do all the buzzers spawn?

Tags: far-cry-4

Where do all the buzzers spawn?

So I'm looking for a source that has a map where you can find all the buzzer spawn locations...

Not the Temporary ones that you can find when you're doing a Golden Path Supplies Drop.

Comment: A tip that's helped me: "Golden Path Supply" missions are dispensed by Gopal via radio. Most of them are given in shacks next to radio towers. A buzzer will be waiting next to these shacks to help you with the missions, but after you do each of these missions its corresponding buzzer no longer spawns. Simply skip these missions until the end of the game, and you'll have a number of buzzers scattered about the map in easy to find locations: just look for the parachute icon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I kinda figured no one would take the time to actually do this, but this is all the buzzer locations I've found ASIDE from the Golden Path Supply Drop Locations. The Locations are highlight in a Red Buzzer Icon.

I really have a feeling a lot of these just showed up randomly. Or after certain missions are complete, some will disappear near that area. Anyway, I don't have the time to really investigate this any further, but here you go. Enjoy.

[image: Big map]

[link to map on Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2mn0.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I found this. You found some locations, but after the missions they disappear.

[image]
[Source](http://forums.ubi.com/showthread.php/977453-Spoiler-Full-map-Locations-animals-Buzzer-Glider-and-more-Forums)

A larger version is available [here](http://extrazoom.com/image-24342.html?s=huln50x50).

Comment: Your post was low quality because it did not add anything useful besides the link. In case the link expires, I added the picture to the post. Please see [How do I write a good answer?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Khilana bazaar always has one on the the east side.